# Graphlab Create SArray apply AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'

Tags: python, attributeerror, graphlab

I'm having trouble applying a function to the values in an SArray object in Graphlab Create (python). The example given in the documentation even fails for me.

```
sa = SArray([1,2,3,4,5])
sa[sa.apply(lambda x: math.log(x) <= 1)]
```

returns the following:

```
RuntimeError: Runtime Exception: 0. Runtime Exception: 0. Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1382, in loads
return Unpickler(file).load()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
dispatch[key](self)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1090, in load_global
klass = self.find_class(module, name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1124, in find_class
__import__(module)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/graphlab/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
import graphlab.connect.aws as aws
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be caused by having multiple Python installations on the machine (the `__import__` through pickle seems to work differently from regular Python imports and may try to load the module from a different path).

The workaround for this is to run in a [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), with a pip install of graphlab-create inside the virtualenv. That should isolate the Python module loading to the correct Python installation and module path.